# Complex model to nested list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm fairly new to both C# and MVC, but I'm trying to use it to build a logging system. Users would view a page and pick from a list of **Categories** then **Event Code** before typing in the incident report.

The model would be:

```cs
public class EventCategory {
    public virtual int eventCategoryId {get; set;}
    public virtual string eventText {get; set;}
    public virtual List<EventCode> eventCodes {get; set;}
}

public class EventCode {
    public virtual int eventCodeId {get; set;}
    public virtual string eventCode {get; set;}
    public virtual string eventCodeLongText {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Event> events {get; set;}
}

public class Event {
    public virtual int eventId {get; set;}
    public virtual string eventText {get; set;}
    public virtual DateTime eventTime {get; set;}
}
```

My view should output:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        Event category 1
        <ul>
            <li>Event Code 1</li>
            <li>Event Code 2</li>
            <li>Event code 3</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Event category 2
        <ul>
            <li>Event Code 3</li> <!--They might overlap -->
            <li>Event Code 4</li>
            <li>Event Code 5</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How do I best achieve this using EF?

Comment: No sure how you expect to 'select' something using `<ul>` and `<li>` elements. You would need a form with cascading dropdowns to select the category, then update the second dropdown with event codes based on the selected category. Alternatively generate links that pass the event code to a controller that generated the view for a new event

Comment: That part I'll get to work. My problem now is that when I use `@for` or `@foreach` on EventCategory, i get that it can't be enumerated. Should I add one more level in the model?

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: If you want to use `@for`/`@foreach` then you'll need a `List<EventCategory>` - this would be in your controller which you haven't included

Comment: @freedomn-m: What would that look like? An owner class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use @for/@foreach then you'll need a List - this would be in your controller which you haven't included, for example:

Under /Models:

```
public class ReportViewModel 
{
    public IList<EventCategory> EventCategories { get;set; }
}
```

In your controller

```
public ActionResult ReportView()
{
    var model = new ReportViewModel();
    //model.EventCategories = ...
    // however you load from your db, eg: db.EventCategories.LoadAll();

    // This assumes you have your EF relationships and/or DB tier 
    // setup correctly so that load eventcategories 
    // also loads each eventcategory.eventCodes

    // possibly:
    model.EventCategories = db.EventCategories.Include("eventCodes").ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

In your view:

```
@model ReportViewModel

<ul>
    @foreach(var cat in Model.EventCategories) 
    {
        <li>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x=>cat.eventText)
            <ul>
                @foreach(var code in cat.eventCodes) 
                {
                    <li>
                        @code.eventCode
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! So the thinking is that the hierarchy ought to end in a single root? One top level?

Comment: Not necessarily.  In your case, you have nested properties that should be populated via the database - your data logic is that of a hierarchy.  In other cases POCOs may not have nested values so that db can be hand-optimised, in which case it would look quite different as you'd load all the lookup data into the viewmodel and they'd all be 'top level'.   In this case, I'd your model as-is.